# How to get exact match from data row using Sql query

Tags: c#, sql, datarow

Hello i've datarow (IDs) as

1. **12?15?6?11?51?**
2. **1?15?6?11?51?**
   &

I want to search numbers which is equal to 1 (id). For That When i used

1. %1% this will return match result as both rows
2. %1?% this will return match result as both rows
3. %?1?% this will return match result as null
4. %?1% this will return match result as both rows

the result should be only 2nd row for ID 1.
Please give proper query for this.
Thanks.

Comment: `ID LIKE '[1][^0-9]%'`

Comment: SQL is a language, please tag the DBMS you are working on eg: SQL Server, MySQL, SQLite ...etc

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
SELECT * FROM TableName WHERE ID LIKE '1?%' OR ID LIKE '%?1?%'
```

Answer (score 0):

`SELECT * FROM TABLE WHERE ID LIKE '1?_%' ;` 
This will work meaning if you contain starting with 1?

Answer (score 0):

You can use

```
CREATE TABLE T(
  ID VARCHAR(45)
);

INSERT INTO T VALUES
('12?15?6?11?51?'),
('1?15?6?11?51? &');

SELECT *
FROM T
WHERE ID LIKE '[1][^0-9]%';
```

**Returns:**

```
+-----------------+
|       ID        |
+-----------------+
| 1?15?6?11?51? & |
+-----------------+
```

**[Demo](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=sqlserver_2017&fiddle=bc9a1757cec00a4ceaa635270cc85d4a)**